# How to load the Section in DotLiquid template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, e-commerce, shopify

I am using DotLiquid for the template. I am working themes same as Shopify. I am facing an issue like I am not able to load 'section' tags. How to render the section tag values. I have 'product.liquid' template inside I am using {% section 'product-template' %}. I am getting the error "[SyntaxException: Unknown tag 'section']". Can anyone please help me out. How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [DotLiquid source on github](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/blob/master/src/DotLiquid/Liquid.cs)

You'll see section is not registered as a tag. You might be able to prompt one of the maintainers to add it but otherwise you could clone the source and add it yourself.